# Android Shared Preference Full Screen not Working

Tags: android, passwords, locking, sharedpreferences

I have created my Login form in xml to my liking and my shared preference does work, but when I add full screen to the java class the app crashes out. Here is my code, any help would be thankful.

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        /*
         * Check if we successfully logged in before. 
         * If we did, redirect to home page
         */
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        if (settings.getString("logged", "").toString().equals("logged")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Password.this, Video.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
                EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

                if(username.getText().toString().length() > 0 && password.getText().toString().length() > 0 ) {
                    //------------------------------------Username below -------------------------------------Password below ---//
                    if(username.getText().toString().equals("username") && password.getText().toString().equals("password")) {

                        /*
                         * So login information is correct, 
                         * we will save the Preference data
                         * and redirect to next class / home  
                         */
                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("logged", "logged");
                        editor.commit();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Password.this, Video.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the crash log...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with `SharedPreferences`. The problem with your code is that you are calling `requestFeature` *after* having set the content for that window. If you check the documentation for `requestFeature`, it says it must be called before `setContentView()` is called (either directly or indirectly).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#requestFeature%28int%29

> public boolean requestFeature (int featureId)
>
> Enable extended screen features. This must be called before setContentView(). May be called as many times as desired as long as it is before setContentView(). If not called, no extended features will be available. You can not turn off a feature once it is requested. You canot use other title features with FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE.

Answer (score 0):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

use this code before setcontentView() in oncreate() method.